# Botão fixo na lateral de um container

Tags: html, css

Tenho um container e dentro dele possuo colunas que dentro tem cards.

Preciso que o meu botão seja fixo na direita dos cards, porém só deve acompanhar o scroll da tela nesse container.

Minha estrutura atual:

```
<div class="container-fluid>

   <div class="col-md-3"> <!-- div do botão !-->
      <a (click)="addVariacao()" class="z-depth-1 waves-effect"><i class="fa fa- 
      plus my-float"></i>
      </a>
      <label (click)="addVariacao()" for="btnAddVariacao" 
      class="tipografiaAdicionaVariacao">Adicionar variação
      </label>
   </div>

   <div class="col-sm-6 col-xl-4" [formGroup]="item"> <!-- div com o card !-->
      <div class="card animated fadeIn cardVariacao">
         CARD
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Os cards são adicionados através da função addVariacao(), a ideia é que conforme for adicionando novos cards o botão "Adicionar variação" siga na lateral direita centralizado no container fluid.

Estou utilizando [Material Design Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver adicionando essa classe na minha div que possui o botão:

```
  .divBotoesVariacao{
    float: right
    position: sticky
    left: 50%
    top: 50%
    transform: translateX(-50%)
  }
```